# Using RSpec, is there a way to assert whether a specific attribute of a Model is invalid?

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to RSpec and I have a test scenario in which I write:

```
my_object.should_not be_valid
```

and it works ok. However, I would like to test whether a particular attribute of the model is not valid. Is such a ready-made RSpec behaviour? Can I write something like:

```
my_object.should_not be_valid(:name)
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to test the number of errors too, with something like:

```
my_object.should_not be_valid(:name => 1)
```

but this is not that important to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2009/1/13/rspec-1-1-12-is-released/), you should be able to write either like this:

```
describe Person do
  it "should validate presence of email" do
    person = Person.new(:email =>; nil)
    person.should_not be_valid
    person.should have(1).error_on(:email)
  end
end
```

Or like below, by using [these rspec matchers](https://github.com/joshknowles/rspec-on-rails-matchers):

```
describe Person do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
end
```

Comment: Ok. The first block is the precise answer to my question. Your second blocak is quite informative and helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just a side note : The github repo you mentioned is quite outdated. This fork (https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/rspec-on-rails-matchers) is more up-to-date and is also provided as a gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-on-rails-matchers). You can also check all the forks : https://github.com/joshknowles/rspec-on-rails-matchers/network